# Upgrading from windows 7 trial to windows 7 ultimate

Tags: windows-7

A few months ago I bought my first laptop. It came with windows 7 Trial. Well yesterday a friend of mine brought me a Windows 7 Ultimate disk because my trial was about to expire.I loaded the Windows 7 Ultimate Program but all of my old files and icons are not present anymore. I want to know how or if it's possible to get all of my old files and icons from my trial version added to my windows 7 ultimate. It was a 64 bit disk and it's an Acer Aspire 5517.

Comment: When you install windows 7, did you happen to reformat your computer?  Because you may have accidentally written over your data.

Comment: Windows 7 is NOT a program. it is an entire operating system.

Answer (score 2):

How did you do the install?
If you did it as an upgrade you should still have all your files and folders.
If you did a Custom (advanced) install and wiped the partitions then you will no Longer have access to the programs files.
Unfortunately from your desciption this looks to be the case.
Sorry to be the bearer of bad tidings.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming your laptop maybe came with a Windows 7 rc verison installed? When installing the retail version of Windows 7 you have to perform a clean install. Which would wipe out of all of your data. As Joe Taylor answered your data is most likely a goner.